# How to set up and connect to a remote mysql database via SSH from Yii2 advanced?

Tags: mysql, ssh, yii2

One of the databases in Yii2 advanced must be connected remotely. Server connects to remote server via SSH. Yii2 as installed on ubuntu server.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the database hostname (e.g. a hostname or an IP address as 127.0.0.1) and port as part of the `dsn` in
`/environments/dev/common/config/main-local.php`:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2advanced',
        ...
    ],
],
```

Docs are here: [Application components](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-connection)